# not able to render icon based on dynamic row data

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to show the icon in sencha touch grid based on the dynamic data of row

here is my code inside a column. but whenever i run the app i see `<img>` tag in a column instead of actual image.

```
renderer:function(value, metaData, record){
    //console.log(value);

    if(value == "0"){

        return "";
    }else if(value == "2"){


          return  '<img src="resources/icons/status_paused.png"/>';


    }else if(value == "3"){

        return "<img src='resources/icons/status_paused.png'/>";

    }else if(value == "4"){

        return "<img src='resources/icons/status_completed.png'/>";
    }
}
```

here is the screenshot of a column

[image]

so far i tried following things but nothing worked

```
metaData.tdCls = "status-update" // where status-update is a class 

metaData.css = "status-update"
```

Comment: Can you please check out what is actually returned by the renderer with a console.log() or by inspecting the cell with developer tools?

Comment: i have checked it using the developer tool its showing `<img src="resources/icons/status_paused.png"/>` only but in a black colored font as if its just a core text value and not an html tag

Comment: Then you need to check what's wrapping that `<img src="resources/icons/status_paused.png"/>`, it's probably inside another property, or maybe you got some bad formatted html before?

Comment: its inside the row div only and there is no bad html formatted here is the content

`<div class="x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-align-left" id="ext-element-257" style="width: 110px;"><img src="/resources/icons/status_paused.png"></div>`

Comment: what i have noticed is if i copy the row from developer tool to text editor its replacing grater then sign and less then sign by `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [Ext.grid.column.Column](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/Column.html#Ext-grid-column-Column) sources, the value returned by the renderer is put into the `nodeValue` of the element:

```
updateCell: function(cell, record, content) {
    if (cell && (record || content)) {
        cell.firstChild.nodeValue = content || this.getCellContent(record);
    }
}
```

Hence it is treated as text. This happens because you are using a column of the wrong type in the column definition for your grid. Use an `Ext.grid.column.Template` instead, which applies your values to an `XTemplate` and puts it in the `innerHtml` of the cell and it should work.

Comment: where should i put this code and do i still need to keep the `rendere` function ?

Comment: You have to change the `updateCell()` of the `Ext.grid.column.Column` component, replacing `nodeValue` with `innerHtml`, you can do that directly modifying the source code of Sencha Touch core, or you can extend `Ext.grid.Grid` to use an extended version of `Ext.grid.column.Column`. Yeah, it's not nice to override two files for such a small change :)

Comment: I looked further into Ext.grid.Grid code and I found out the solution is already available in Sencha, without need for overrides.